# R Base plotting, how to add a bold layer to mtext?

Tags: r, plot, aesthetics

```
mtext("Females", outer=TRUE)
```

I want to make the outer title bold but I am unable to add a bold layer to it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like [this:](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html)

```
x11() 
par(oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
plot(1)
mtext("bla", outer = T, font = 2) # font = 2 <- bold
```